# Energy spectrum of Solar energetic particles (SEP's)

Tags: astrophysics, plasma-physics, sun, solar-wind

I would like to know if we have obtained any observations regarding the energy spectrum of solar energetic particles. Something like the following histogram :

[image]

And if so, what is the index of the power-law. Thank you!

Comment: seems to me your question might be answered in the future, as there are a number of experiments going on . https://www.vox.com/the-highlight/2019/7/16/17690740/cosmic-rays-universe-theory-science for a layman review of sosmic rays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to know if we have obtained any observations regarding the energy spectrum of solar energetic particles.

Yes, there are several decades (>30 years) worth of observations of [solar energetic particles (SEP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_energetic_particles) [e.g., *Desai et al.*, 2016a,b; *Reames*, 2017].

> And if so, what is the index of the power-law. Thank you!

There is not one, but two for each mass-per-charge chemical abundance.  The [solar wind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_wind) already contains multiple heavy ions above protons, including but not limited to [alpha-particles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_particle) (i.e., helium nuclei), carbon, nitrogen, oxygen, neon, magnesium, silicon, sulpher, calcium, and iron [e.g., *Desai et al.*, 2016b; *Reames*, 2017].

The spectra, in terms of particle fluence $j(E)$, are described by a double- or broken-power-law [e.g., *Desai et al.*, 2016a], given by:
$$
\begin{align}
  j\left( E \right) & = C \ E^{-\gamma_{a}} \ e^{-E/E_{B}} \text{  for  } E \leq \left( \gamma_{b} - \gamma_{a} \right) \ E_{B} \tag{0a} \\
  j\left( E \right) & = C \ E^{-\gamma_{b}} \ \left[ \left( \gamma_{b} - \gamma_{a} \right) \ E_{B} \right]^{\gamma_{b} - \gamma_{a}} \ e^{-\left( \gamma_{b} - \gamma_{a} \right)} \text{  for  } E > \left( \gamma_{b} - \gamma_{a} \right) \ E_{B} \tag{0b}
\end{align}
$$

It turns out that the type of solar event (e.g., [solar flare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_flare)) that causes the SEP also matters in regards to the slopes and the flux vs time profile [e.g., *Reames*, 2017].

## **References**

- Desai, M.I., *et al.*, "Spectral Properties of Large Gradual Solar Energetic Particle Events. I. Fe, O, and Seed Material," *Astrophys. J.* **816**(2), pp. 68, doi:[10.3847/0004-637X/816/2/68](https://doi.org/10.3847/0004-637X/816/2/68), 2016a
- Desai, M.I., *et al.*, "Spectral Properties of Large Gradual Solar Energetic Particle Events. II. Systematic Q/M Dependence of Heavy Ion Spectral Breaks," *Astrophys. J.* **828**(2), pp. 106, doi:[10.3847/0004-637X/828/2/106](https://doi.org/10.3847/0004-637X/828/2/106), 2016b.
- Reames, D.V. "Solar Energetic Particles," *Lecture Notes in Physics* **932**, doi:[10.1007/978-3-319-50871-9](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-319-50871-9), 2017.

Comment: great answer!! Thank you very much!